# Is there a "commit" for fprintf? (Prevent data-loss when server dies)

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I write Server for client-server application in C. I have to save logs to file.

I write it into a file using fprintf, but when the server go down I lost the data in the file, cause I don't close filedescriptor, is there any function which tell my program save the data?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fflush after every fprintf it helps.

Comment: Also, fflush((FILE*)NULL) will flush all open files

Answer (score 2):

`fflush` should do what you want — it ensures all output is explicitly written to the file rather than e.g. being cached for later writing. So that moves the data out of user space.

`sync` can then be used — it causes all buffered file changes to be physically written (though per the spec it needn't block until the writes are complete, so you can be certain they've started but not that they've finished).